# Python - web2py - Using a class to draw a rectangle (or image) onto a canvas

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, html5-canvas, web2py

I am making a program for a school project that requires me to place images in a collage onto a canvas. I have created a class with methods that creates all the necessary numbers (coordinates, size, etc) to place an image (or a rectangle for testing purposes). However I am unsure of how to make it so that I can call these methods to get HTML to draw the rectangles in the right places.

What I have in index.html:

```
<script>
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    {{makeMosaic.drawRectangle(0)}}
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect({{=session.space[0][0]}}, {{=session.space[0][1]}}, {{=session.space[1][0]-session.space[0][0]}}, {{=session.space[1][1]-session.space[0][1]}});
</script>
```

and what I have in default.py:

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
except:
    import Image
import os

@auth.requires_login()
def index():
    ... irrelevant code ...
    makeMosaic = Mosaic(3508, 4960, 2)
    makeMosaic.divideEmpty(0, 1000, 1200)
    return dict(Ufname = Ufname, Utype = Utype, makeMosaic=makeMosaic)


... irrelevant code...

class Mosaic:
    def __init__(self, c_x_size, c_y_size, c_id):
        self.c_x_size = c_x_size #Canvas x size
        self.c_y_size = c_y_size #Canvas y size
        self.image_sizes = [] #A list of the sizes of each image. Formatted like: [[x,y],[x,y],[x,y]...]
        self.c_id = c_id
        images = db().select(db.image.ALL, orderby=db.image.id)
        for image in images:
            if image.canvas_id == self.c_id:
                img = Image.open(os.path.join(request.folder, "uploads", image.file), "r")
                self.image_sizes.append([img.size[0], img.size[1]])
        self.emptyspace = [[[0,0],[self.c_x_size, self.c_y_size]]] #The list for the empty spaces. Formatted like: [[[top left x & y],[bottom right x & y]]]

    def divideEmpty(self, imgInd, x_place, y_place):
        ... irrelevant code...

    def addImage(self, imgInd, x_place, y_place):
        ... irrelevant code...

    def drawRectangle(self, spaceInd):
        session.space = self.emptyspace[spaceInd]
```

So I'm trying to call drawRectangle in index.html so that I can draw a second, different rectangle.

Comment: You can't call Python code from HTML. Python runs on server, not in the browser. You'll either have to use JavaScript, or make the collage on the server as an image and then send this image in a response to the browser.